# Is background independence necessary for loop quantum gravity in itself, or only necessary to make LQG compatible with special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, loop-quantum-gravity

At first look the idea of particulate space in loop quantum gravity would seem to indicate a preferred frame or ether, but theorists have gone to great lengths to prove the background independence of LQG theory.  Have they done this in order to prove that LQG is compatible with special relativity, or is background independence necessary for LQG to function in itself?

Comment: Do you mean GR not SR?

Comment: @Eletie certainly special relativity

Comment: Background independence is a property of GR not SR, so I'm unsure what you're asking. LQG is manifestly background independent, you could say it's one of the guiding premises (as it's built from GR). I don't see what SR has to do with it.

Comment: @Eletie  Perhaps I'm using my terminology incorrectly.   In his concept about a modified Lorentz ether, Hatch specifically refers to special relativity when he discusses that GPS clocks are not adjusted relative to one another. Instead they are adjusted as a function of their velocity with respect to the Earth centered inertial frame. This would imply a preferred frame, or background dependence, would it not?   This is what I am really asking about, why does LQG not require a preferred frame, when at first look it would appear that such a frame is implicit in the basic idea of space particles.

Comment: I'm not sure who you're referring to or the context so I'm afraid I can't give any useful answer - I'll leave it to somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At first look the idea of particulate space in loop quantum gravity would seem to indicate a preferred frame or ether

Not at all – if you're saying this, you're probably not familiar with the mathematics of LQG. LQG is background-independent pretty much by construction. Also, background independence doesn't just mean that there's no preferred inertial frame of reference aka ether, the idea goes way beyond that (you'll need to study General Relativity and/or LQG to understand the physical implications of background independence).

> Have they done this in order to prove that LQG is compatible with special relativity, or is background independence necessary for LQG to function in itself?

Special Relativity is a special case, in fact, a solution of the e.o.m. of General Relativity. The specific solution that corresponds to Special Relativity is called the Minkowski space.

The Minkowski space is a special kind of background. GR is background independent, but SR is not: it is based on a specific solution of GR. This scenario is encountered a lot throughout physics, it is known as "symmetry breaking".

LQG is a quantization of General Relativity, so in the classical limit it reproduces General Relativity, and hence also Special Relativity.

Comment: Thanks very much.  You've answered it very clearly.